# how to get the value when onclick and again on click value should be removed in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a page where an anchor tag has id. When the anchor tag is clicked I am fetching the value to input type hidden and after again clicking on the same div it should be removed. The selection will be in a loop. Please check my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".get_category").on('click', function(){  
        var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#categories"+cat_id).val(cat_id);
    })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zu17bn4/

Comment: Where's the value you are getting?

Comment: the value from database. have you seen jsfiddle

Comment: _when anchor tag is clicked i am fetching the value to input type hidden and after again clicking on the same div_ ! you click on tag or on div !!

Comment: Can you please explain what you are missing? what do you want the help with?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is?

Comment: I think he wants the value inside the hidden element

Comment: Like check and uncheck. i click the value should be in hidden type if the user unclick the tag the value should be removed from hidden type

Comment: Okay, The value of which element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add these lines :

```
$(".get_category").on('click', function(){  
        var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($("#categories"+cat_id).val() == '')
            $("#categories"+cat_id).val(cat_id);
        else
            $("#categories"+cat_id).val('');
})
```

Comment: Great working thanks man and also how to limit when clicking 5 to 6 services in a loop

Comment: Well for this you ll have to add a count in your function, for example on the else you add : count_category = count_category+1;. Remember to initiate your count_category variable to 0 in a scope above the function to make it persistent  ( var count_category = 0 ; )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle:

on each click I check the value, if it is available I remove it if it's not there I set it.

Added: cat_id variable

https://jsfiddle.net/0zu17bn4/4/

```
$(".get_category").on('click', function(){  
        var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $hiddenField =  $("#categories"+cat_id);
        if(!$hiddenField.val()){
            $hiddenField.val(cat_id);
        }
        else{
            $hiddenField.val("");
        }               
})
```

Comment: not adding the value to hidden type you missed getting catid variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a condition on hidden input every time the anchor clicked to check if the value is empty or not, like following :

```js
$(".get_category").on('click', function(){ 
 
    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var input_hidden = $("#categories"+$(this).attr('id'));
    
    if(input_hidden.val()=="")
     input_hidden.val(cat_id);
    else
        input_hidden.val("");
    
    alert("Hidden input value ="+input_hidden.val()); 
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 home_s"> 
    <a class="get_category" id="36" href="javascript:void(0)">
        <img class="img-responsive img-center" src=""/>
        <span>test</span>
    </a>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="categories[]" id="categories36" value=""/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".get_category").on('click', function(){ 

    var cat_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("#categories"+cat_id).val() == "")
    {
        $("#categories"+cat_id).val(cat_id);
    }
    else
    {
         $("#categories"+cat_id).val("");
    }
 });
```

check if the element value is empty or not. if empty then add value in it. otherwise remove value from it.